# Greedy Algorithm in "C"

Tags: c, algorithm, greedy

I'm just start learning `C language`. I wrote this C code to implement Greedy algorithm
I don't know what mistake I've made with this code, that code seems fine but its not working as I expected. Can anybody help me to fix this code?

```
int main(void) {
    float amount = 0;
    int cents = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int amount_left = 0;

    amount = .30;

    cents = (int)round(amount * 100);

    printf("%d", cents);

    amount_left = cents;

    while (cents - 25 >= 0) {
        count = count + 1;
        amount_left = cents - 25;
    }
    while (amount_left - 10 >= 0) {
        count = count + 1;
        amount_left = amount_left - 10;
    }
    while (amount_left - 5 >= 0) {
        count = count + 1;
        amount_left = amount_left - 5;
    }
    while (amount_left - 1 >= 0) {
        count = count + 1;
        amount_left = amount_left - 1;
    }
    printf("You get %d coins\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Print `count` instead of `amount_left`?

Comment: It would be clearer if you wrote `while (cents >= 25) ...`, wouldn't it?  (Fortran II required the sort of comparison you show, always comparing to zero; Fortran IV -- aka Fortran 66 -- got beyond that.)  There's also a useful operator written `/` and another written `%` that can make this better.

Comment: @PatriceGahide
Thanks! but still i'm not getting the output..

Comment: In your first `while()` loop, what happens if `cents` is greater than 25? How many times will this loop repeat before exiting?

Comment: If you can't see why the first `while` loop has a bug, it's really worth taking the exact code that you have posted and stepping through it with a debugger. You'll quickly realize what the problem is then.

Comment: Thank you guys!
I solved it by your suggestions...
yeah! there is bug in first while loop....
i know this code looks ugly but finally i got result...
Thanks for ur help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notes about the problems in the code:

- You are using in the first loop `cents` when there would be `amount_left`, in the case of the first loop if it require more that one iteration, the result would be incorrect.
- As recommended is better to change `amount_left - 10 >= 0` by `amount_left >= 10`.
- The final `printf` statement most probably (by the text) is for printing the count of coin gained by the amount provided.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float amount = 0;
    int cents = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int amount_left = 0;

    amount = .30;

    cents = (int)round(amount * 100);

    printf("%d\n", cents);

    amount_left = cents;

    while (amount_left >= 25) {
        count++;
        amount_left -= 25;
    }
    while (amount_left >= 10) {
        count++;
        amount_left -= 10;
    }
    while (amount_left >= 5) {
        count++;
        amount_left -= 5;
    }
    while (amount_left >= 1) {
        count = count + 1;
        amount_left -= 1;
    }
    printf("You get %d coins\n", count);
}
```

Using the formula: `initial_amount` = `coin value` * `coin used` + `amount_left`

This could be write in C as:

- `initial_amount` / `coin value` = `coin used`
- `initial_amount` % `coin value` = `amount_left`

More optimized solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float amount = 0;
    int cents = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int amount_left = 0;

    amount = .30;

    cents = (int)round(amount * 100);

    printf("%d\n", cents);

    amount_left = cents;          // beginning with 30 cents

    count += amount_left / 25;    // 30 / 25 = 1,      one 25 cent coin
    amount_left %= 25;            // 30 % 25 = 5,      left with 5 cents

    count += amount_left / 10;    // 5 / 10 = 0        no coin used
    amount_left %= 10;            // 5 % 10 = 5        left the same 5 cents

    count += amount_left / 5;     // 5 / 5 = 1         one 5 cent coin
    amount_left %= 5;             // 5 % 5 = 0         left with 0 cents

    count += amount_left;        // not needed 1 cent coins.

    printf("You get %d coins\n", count);
}
```

Notes:

- There is no need to `while loop` operation `17 / 5 = 3` in integers arithmetic in `C` and `17 % 5 = 2`.
- Using this you use for a coin of value `N`, `amount / N` coins count (could be 0, eg: `amount = 9` and `N = 10`, `9/10 = 0` in integer division) and the amount left is `amount % N`.
- The last case (for coin of 1) always left `amount = 0`.

Comment: Thanks everyone!
actually i'm a beginner in C
I don't understand how the optimized solution works!
if you don't mind can you explain by comments in between code?

Comment: @user3342450: the `/` is an integer (whole number) division. For example, `30 / 25` returns `1`. The `%` operator is called modulo or modulus and returns the remainder of a division. For example, `30 % 25` returns `5`. Then, `x = x + y;` can be abbreviated as `x += y;` and the same with `x = x % y;` which can be abbreviated as `x %= y;`. Step through this code with a debugger to gain more insight.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with NetVipeC's answer.

I would add a note that is probably out of your assignment's scope, but might help you create better code in the future:

Your code suffers from [code duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code). To eliminate that, I would create a function and call that function several times with different arguments. This process is called [code reuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse). code reuse is neccesary for writing more complicated programs. Code:

```
// a user-defined function that counts the number of coins with a specific value used 
int count_number_of_coins(int amount_left, int coin_value) {
    int count = 0;
    while(amount_left >= coin_value) {
        count++;
        amount_left -= coin_value;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    float amount = 0;
    int cents = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int amount_left = 0;
    int coin_values[] = {25, 10, 5, 1}; // an array of ints that hold the values of the coins in cents.
    int i;

    amount = .30;

    cents = (int)round(amount * 100);

    printf("%d", cents);

    amount_left = cents;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        int current_count = count_number_of_coins(amount_left, coin_values[i]);
        amount_left -= current_count*coin_values[i];
        count += current_count;
    }

    printf("You get %d coins\n", count);
}
```

I know this code might look wierd now. I've used a few key features of the `C language` that you will probably learn soon: `user-defined function`, `array` and `for loop`.

Hope this helps. Best of luck with your studies!

---

Edit:

If you don't wanna use a user-defined function, you can avoid code duplication without it. Basically you just pour the function's content inside the main function (and change names of variables):

```
int main(void) {
    float amount = 0;
    int cents = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int amount_left = 0;
    int coin_values[] = {25, 10, 5, 1}; // an array of ints that hold the values of the coins in cents.
    int i;

    amount = .30;

    cents = (int)round(amount * 100);

    printf("%d", cents);

    amount_left = cents;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        while(amount_left >= coin_values[i]) {
            count++;
            amount_left -= coin_values[i];
        }
    }

    printf("You get %d coins\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i will learn all the features ASAP coz this code looks pretty good than mine..

Comment: No problem. I've edited the answer have a simpler implementation.